# Use main query condition on sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "products" and a table "links". every product can have multiple links, each link can have many sales, clicks and impressions, but doesn't necessarily have all of them. I want to get a list of links of a certain product matching some criteria for them. I want to get this data grouped per day and campaign and link banner size.

The following query works correctly, but it's much slower than it could be. The problem is that the subqueries get the data for all link ids and it's just filtered in the end. The overall query would become much faster if the sub queries included something like
`where product_id IN (...)` but I only know the link_ids from the main query, not before

if I try to add
`where link_id = l.id`
it's obviously an unknown column, because the sub query doesn't have access to the main queries results.

how can I let the sub queries only look up data for the link_Ids that the main query found? I could split it up to 2 complete separate queries, but is this possible in one query?

```
select p.id, p.name, l.id, l.banner_size, 
                    coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'sales' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_sales,
                    coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'clicks' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_clicks,
                    coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'impressions' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_impressions,
                    t1.dt
                from links l
                inner join products p
                    on p.id = l.product_id
                left join
                    (
                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(clicked) dt, 'sales' as col 
                        from sales
                        where clicked >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and clicked <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(clicked), link_id

                    union all

                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(created) dt, 'clicks' 
                        from clicks_source1
                        where created >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and created <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(created), link_id

                    union all

                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(time) dt, 'clicks' 
                        from clicks_source2
                        where time >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and time <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(time), link_id

                    union all

                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(created) dt, 'impressions' 
                        from impression_source1
                        where created > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and created <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(created), link_id

                    union all

                    select count(1) as ct, link_id, date(time) dt, 'impressions' 
                        from impression_source2
                        where time > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and time <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
                        group by date(time), link_id        

                    ) t1 on t1.link_id = l.id
                where l.agent_id = 300 
                and p.id = 3454
                and l.banner_size = 48
                and p.company NOT IN (13592, 28189) 
                group by c.id, l.banner_size, t1.dt
                having (total_sales + total_clicks + total_impressions) > 0
                order by dt DESC, p.id ASC, l.banner_size ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

What you'd like to use is called lateral joins, but MySQL doesn't feature them.

One solution is to move the subqueries for the counts to the select clause:

```
select 
  id,
  name,
  coalesce((select count(*) from views v where v.product_id = p.product_id), 0)
    as total_views,
  coalesce((select count(*) from clicks c where c.product_id = p.product_id), 0)
    as total_clicks
from products
where status = 1;
```

It is unnecessary that you combined views and clicks in one subquery. Maybe it's just this, that kept the optimizer from getting a better execution plan. You can try the following and check whether it's already much faster than your original query.

```
select 
  p.id,
  p.name,
  coalesce(v.total, 0) as total_views
  coalesce(c.total, 0) as total_clicks
from products
left join (select product_id, count(*) as total from views group by product_id) v
  on v.product_id = p.product_id
left join (select product_id, count(*) as total from clicks group by product_id) c
  on c.product_id = p.product_id
where p.status = 1;
```

Comment: that's a good idea, but I'm not sure if it's possible to adapt to my case. Maybe I simplified too much, I added the full query. The data gathered is also grouped by date, when I tried your to remove the union and use multiple left joins instead, the group by date returned wrong results. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You say that your example is much simplified. Maybe you can just apply the condition early by repeating it. E.g.:

```
select p.id, p.name,
coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'views' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_views,
coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'clicks' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_clicks
from products p
left join
    (
    select count(1) as ct, product_id, 'views' as col
    from views
    where product_id in (select product_id from products where status = 1)
    group by product_id

    union all

    select count(1) as ct, product_id, 'clicks' as col
    from clicks
    where product_id in (select product_id from products where status = 1)
    group by product id
    ) t1 on t1.product_id = p.product_id
where p.status = 1;
```

Or with a `WITH` clause:

```
with p as (select * from products where status = 1)
select p.id, p.name,
coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'views' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_views,
coalesce(sum(case when t1.col = 'clicks' then ct else 0 end), 0) as total_clicks
from p
left join
    (
    select count(1) as ct, product_id, 'views' as col
    from views
    where product_id in (select product_id from p)
    group by product_id

    union all

    select count(1) as ct, product_id, 'clicks' as col
    from clicks
    where product_id in (select product_id from p)
    group by product id
    ) t1 on t1.product_id = p.product_id
;
```